# Unable to run the `make` command

Tags: linux, ubuntu, makefile, gnu-make

I am trying to run the `make` command over the NVIDIA CUDA Sample files. I navigated to the directory and typed `make`. Below is the output.

```
root@ubuserver3:/home/ubuadmin/CUDA/SampleInstalled/NVIDIA_CUDA-5.5_Samples# make
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/ubuadmin/CUDA/SampleInstalled/NVIDIA_CUDA-5.5_Samples/0_Simple/simpleAssert'
"/home/ubuadmin/CUDA"/bin/nvcc -ccbin g++ -I../../common/inc  -m32    -gencode arch=compute_20,code=sm_20 -gencode arch=compute_30,code=sm_30 -gencode arch=compute_35,code=\"sm_35,compute_35\" -o simpleAssert.o -c simpleAssert.cu
g++: No such file or directory
make[1]: *** [simpleAssert.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/ubuadmin/CUDA/SampleInstalled/NVIDIA_CUDA-5.5_Samples/0_Simple/simpleAssert'
make: *** [0_Simple/simpleAssert/Makefile.ph_build] Error 2
root@ubuserver3:/home/ubuadmin/CUDA/SampleInstalled/NVIDIA_CUDA-5.5_Samples#
```

There is an error which I do not understand why.

Comment: *where* is the error you don't understand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you search you'll find many answers for this question.  Basically, you don't have a compiler installed on your system.

Since you're running Ubuntu, run `sudo apt-get install build-essential` to get all the packages needed to compile software.